# Can't focus on editable link with IE

Tags: javascript, html

I dispose of the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <a id="toto" contenteditable="true">Button</a>
</body>

<script>
  var elt= document.getElementById('toto');
  elt.focus();
</script>
</html>
```

When the page is loaded, the cursor is already in place and you just have to type what you want. The trouble is that it doesn't work with IE11.

Since this works with other tags like `<div>`, I assume I just have to make `<a>` focusable for IE. Any ideas how ?

Comment: Silly question but if it works with <div>, why not use <div> instead of <a>?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Sadly, I don't control the component's structure.

Comment: Ah but you can! Change its innerHTML on page load to a div with a new id and contenteditable true and then add the focus to that instead? Just an idea, probably a better way out there tho

Comment: @param Didn't think of that, I'll try so. The trouble is, these components are heavily used, so I'm not confortable with changing them too much :) . I'll see if there exists a 'cleaner' way

Comment: Doesn’t work for me even if I change the `a` element to a `div` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, IE automatically focuses on the `body` element after the page has loaded. So if your code is *exactly* as in the question, it will set focus on the `a` element but this will be overridden a few nanoseconds later, after the `load` event is triggered. A simple way to avoid this is to make sure the focus is set only after load. Example:

```
<a id="toto" contenteditable="true">Button</a>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var elt= document.getElementById('toto');
  elt.focus();
}
</script>
```

But IE also seems to have an issue with setting focus on an `a` element without an `href` attribute. Whatever the cause might be, you can circumvent this a) by adding `href="javascript:;"`, but this is awkward and causes link formatting to be applied, or b) by changing the `a` element to e.g. a `span` element;

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! The timeout was not needed in the original code but I would not have found for the `href`. Would you know if this behaviour is described somewhere ?